# Android how to start intent with 2 classes in one activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

i have an activity separated to 2 classes:

```
ShipmentListActivity -> class ShipmentListActivity 
                     -> class GetContacts (asynchronous processing of JSON data)
```

Im trying to redirect on this activity using the:

```
Intent activity = new Intent(ScanActivity.this,
                    ShipmentListActivity.class);
// pass data to next activity
activity.putExtra("list_of_found_shipments", result.toString());
startActivity(activity);
```

Problem is that in intent creation always get error:

```
ShipmentListActivity cannot be resolved to a type
```

How can i solve it without separating into 2 standalone classes?

Thanks for any advice.

### HERE IS EXAMPLE OF ACTIVITY WHERE I WANT TO REDIRECT:

```
public class ShipmentListActivity extends ListActivity
{
     private ProgressDialog pDialog;


        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);

            // get shipment data passed from previous activity 
            Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
            if (extras != null) {
                String value = extras.getString("list_of_found_shipments");
                try {
                    jsonDataObject = new JSONObject(value);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e(GlobalApplication.APP_LOG_NAMESPACE,
                            "JSONException convert");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }


            // Calling async task to get json
            new GetContacts().execute();
        }



          /**
             * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
             * */
            private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

                …
            }

        }
```

Comment: Is `ShipmentListActivity.java` in the same package? Also show its structure in the question. Like `public class ShipmentListActivity extends Activity{ ...class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<>{ ... } } `

Comment: I just add activity example

Comment: Did you try Ctrl+Shift+o ?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code (Not sure what it means that an activity is "seperated into two classes"?) but you need to give the intent the class that derives from Activity. If that is a nested class you need to do it like this:

```
Intent activity = new Intent(ScanActivity.this, ShipmentListActivity.ShipmentListActivity.class);
```

Comment: I just add activity example.